# How to iterate through <span>s with Arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a few spans:

```
<span>Item 1</span>
<span>Item 2</span>
<span>Item 3</span>
```

The items are all next to another. I would like the user to press the arrow keys (left & right) & then move through the spans (in my case this would update the current object and dispatch an action).

Edit: I do not have any sample code, as I am an absolute beginner. But I also do not expect anyone to post a working solution here, I would just like to have some general advice how I would conceptually approach this in React/Redux.

Comment: try binding key press events to the parent of all spans and manually move to next() and previous() of current span based on key pressed

Comment: Any trial code? use `<>` icon to post some code.

Comment: Can you show your attempted code, and explain where you got stuck?

Comment: No sample code, absolute beginner here. I also don't expect a coded solution here, just a few hint how I could approach this in react along the lines of @VinodLouis (thanks a lot already!)

Comment: Attach `onKey` to parent component, in the handler, call `this.setState({ activeSpan: x });` Render active span using highlight color.

Comment: Look into jQuery, it's much easier to use for these things than pure JS, and pretty easy to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a plain JavaScript example:

```js
function move(dir) {
    var selectables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.selectable'));
    var selected = document.querySelector('.selected');
    var i = selectables.indexOf(selected);
    i = (i+selectables.length+dir)%selectables.length;
    selected.classList.remove('selected');
    selectables[i].classList.add('selected');
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    switch(e.which) {
    case 37: return move(-1);
    case 39: return move(1);
    }
});
```

```css
.selected { background-color: yellow }
```

```html
<span class="selectable selected">Item 1</span>
<span class="selectable">Item 2</span>
<span class="selectable">Item 3</span>
<p>Set focus on this page and press left/right arrow keys
```