# Get id's of multiple <span> elements on selection? (React)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, electron, react-redux

In React, I create `<span>`'s out of an array which gives me words. I then have, for example, :

```
<span> bla </span> <span> bla </span> <span> bla </span>
```

I also assign unique identifiers (keys) to each span, (in the form of ids) which I also get from the original array.

**Problem:**

I would now like the user to *select* words, - not by clicking on them individually, but actually *select* them (so that the background of the words becomes blue).

Whenever the user does this, I would like to get back the id's of the selected spans. How could I implement something like this?

I am using React, Redux & electron.

Comment: check this answer, may be it will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43255383/5185595

Comment: Check the [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Selection) + [selectstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectstart) docus ;)

Comment: @MayankShukla No that does not help very much. First, the answer is plain javascript. Second, I still don't know how to do the selection bit of the code, and extract the id's from a user selection.

Answer (score 0):

Cause I was super bored :D

This is a listener for the selection change event:
[MDN Selection Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Selection)
Keep in mind: you'l have to check if the selection was the full word etc.
pls check **the docu** and **the debugger** to see how Selection behaves ;)

```js
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', () => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const selectedText = selection.toString();
  const selectedElement = selection.focusNode.parentNode;
  const wordIndex = this.words.indexOf(selectedText);

  if( wordIndex !== -1) {
    alert('you selected a word from the list with id:' + selectedElement.id);
  }
});
```

in a react component (ES6) it could look like this [SelectionDemo](http://jsbin.com/lezuqujaju/1/edit?html,js,output)

edit:
- If you have a big array of words, think about to use throttling, cause selectionchange will trigger for each change (char by char)
- you could also use a stateless component which would shorten the code